# what is the difference between 拒否する　and 断る

Tags: word-choice

I'm referring especially to the context of rejecting someone, e.g. if they asked you on a date.

Answer (score 2):

I think 拒否する sounds stronger than 断る.

断る can mean "decline" or "turn down", while 拒否する would be more like "refuse", like saying "No./Never./No way!"

Comment: (By the way, I think 拒絶する ("reject"?) sounds even stronger.)